# How get ALL url pictures of post with Facebook4J?

Tags: java, facebook

I'm getting an URL picture of a Post as below:

```
ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebookClient.getFeed("*******",new Reading().limit(20));
Post post = feeds.get(i);
URL imageURL= post.getPicture();
```

If there is a post with more than one pictures I just get the first.. It is possible to get ALL pictures with Facebook4J ?